# Do resources need to be connected to roads?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization 4, you had to connect an improved resource to your capital via roads/rivers.  Is there any such requirement in Civilization 5?  Or is it enough to just get them within your territory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They'll just need to be in your territory. Building roads is only helpful in between cities, due to the high maintenance cost.  The age of endless road-sprawl is finally at an end!

It is important to note that you'll need to build the corresponding improvement on top of the resource to "capture" it.

Comment: Yet the advisor still recommends you to build a road on top of the resource. Are there any benefits on doing that or is it just a bug? It literally says "It will connect the Luxury resource in this tile to our trade network improving the empire's happiness!" This is with the God&Kings expansion.